# gRPC failed with StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses

Tags: debian, command-line-interface, debian-buster, grpc

I am trying to set up [Tinode](https://tinode.co) messenger on Debian 10 Buster server.
For some reason when I run a Pyhon command to access messenger's grpc service on localhost, port 16060:

```
python tn-cli.py --login-basic=alice:alice123
```

server returns:

```
gRPC failed with StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses.
```

It's a fresh installed server (on OVH). Below is lsof output. The second line looks strange to me.
After installing the server I changed the hostname un even rebooted the server. But as you can see, there still appears "old-host-name". And what is IP address 104.18.55.244? It's Cloudflare's IP address but the domain on the server has nothing to do with Cloudflare.

```
lsof -i
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
tinode  2757 debian    6u  IPv6  30224      0t0  TCP localhost:37110->localhost:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
tinode  2757 debian    7u  IPv4  30232      0t0  TCP old-host-name:35186->104.18.55.244:https (ESTABLISHED)
tinode  2757 debian    8u  IPv4  23484      0t0  TCP localhost:16060 (LISTEN)
tinode  2757 debian    9u  IPv6  30236      0t0  TCP *:6060 (LISTEN)

nc -vz localhost 16060
localhost [127.0.0.1] 16060 (?) open
```

**/etc/hosts file:**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

::1     localhost       ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       new.mynewhostname.com        new
```

What's wrong that grcp fails? I spent the whole day with it. Disabled the firewall, bit nothing helps.